# conditional selections : do not select B , unless A is selected

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

a boy has 3 library tickets , and 8 books of his interest in the library , of these 8 he does not want to borrow book B unless book A is also borrowed . in how many ways can he choose the three books to be borrowed

my answer is 6c1 + 6c3
but the given solution is 7c2 + 6c3

this is a HOTS ( high order thinking skills ) question
according to you which is correct and why?

edit: how i arrived at my answer :
there are 2 possibilities , he will pick book A , or NOT

1. he picks book A , then he must be picking book B as well ( so far 2 book ) , now you can select 1 more book from leftover 8-2=6 books in the following ways : 6c1
2. in second case , he does not picks book A ( and not B as well ) , so he will now select 3 books from remaining 8-2=6 ( we subtracted 2 bcz he is not picking book A and B )  , no of ways to pick 3 book sout of 6 = 6c3
3. total them giving 6c1 + 8c3

```
edit2
Thanks a lot everyone. here is the summarized answer:  
"B is not selected unless A is also selected" in simpler terms implies that "B can be selected only when A is also selected"  
my mistake was assuming that when A is selected , then B must also be selected in a group.
```

Comment: We could help you better if you explained how you got your answer. Perhaps you made a small error in calculation; perhaps it's something more involved. We won't know until you show us. Please [edit] the question accordingly

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Also, please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Why this Answer is Wrong?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath sir please suggest me a title , i am newbie

Comment: What about if he *does* pick $A$ and does *not* pick book $B$?  The only requirement was that *if* $B$ was picked then $A$ must also be picked, but the reverse is not required.

Comment: Note that $\binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{2}=\binom{7}{2}$

Comment: @jmoravitz sir would you please explain

Comment: You claim incorrectly "*he picks book A, then he must be picking B as well.*"  That is wrong.  Do not confuse the phrase '*if P then Q*" with the phrase "*P if and only if Q*".  Do not confuse the statement $P\implies Q$ with the statement $P\iff Q$.  All we are told is that if $B$ was selected then $A$ must also have been selected.  That does not imply that if $A$ was selected then $B$ was also selected.  It is possible that $A$ is selected while $B$ is not selected and it is these outcomes that you did not count and why your answer is off by an amount of $\binom{6}{2}$ from the correct count

Comment: "*Healthy*" horses have four legs.  Your desk may also have four legs, but is clearly not a healthy horse.

Comment: I'm not writing the title for you, but if it includes things like "choose", "ways",... it will at least be clear that it is a question about combinatorics

Comment: You know, I imagine I'm barely older than you are, but here's some life advice: making the effort to write formally, or at least capitalizing your letters and adding punctuations where necessary, goes a long way and tells your readers you take what you are learning seriously. Writing with basic grammar shows that you respect the more experienced and educated people who want to help you out.

Comment: @accerelator Noted. I will try my best to follow the correct structure from now on. Thank you.

Comment: @siddh2e3 Please, avoid using the word "sir". You're assuming that you're addressing to a man, but that could be not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $^6c_3$ is ok we can choose any 3 books out of $6$ if A and B are excluded.

Now given that he will only choose B if A is chosen.
But there is no guarantee that he will choose B after he chooses A, he may not take B for eg the triple may contain A C D.
Thus after fixing A, there are $2$ choices to make hence$^7C_2$ ways.